# Azure ADF Dataflow to convert json into rows and columns

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm having a bit of difficulty converting the following (simplified) json into rows and columns within a dataflow activity. The first step in the dataflow is to call an API which returns json, I then need to convert that json into something tabular for insertion into a SQL table.

The json represents a survey and it's questions.

```
{
    "result": {
        "id": "abcdef123",
        "name": "survey name",
        "isActive": true,
        "expiration": {
            "startDate": null,
            "endDate": null
        },
        "questions": {
            "QID16": {
                "questionType": {
                    "type": "DB",
                    "selector": "TB",
                    "subSelector": null
                },
                "questionText": "questions text 16",
                "questionLabel": null,
                "questionName": "question name 16"
            },
            "QID18": {
                "questionType": {
                    "type": "DB",
                    "selector": "TB",
                    "subSelector": null
                },
                "questionText": "questions text 18",
                "questionLabel": null,
                "questionName": "question name 18"
            },
            "QID21": {
                "questionType": {
                    "type": "DB",
                    "selector": "TB",
                    "subSelector": null
                },
                "questionText": "questions text 21",
                "questionLabel": null,
                "questionName": "question name 21"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I'd have liked to have done was use a flatten activity and unrolled on the questions property, but the questions property is not a list. Also the QID## question identifiers will vary from survey to survey so I'm looking to avoid hardcoding any solution to these, the number of these questions on each survey can vary from as little as 5 to 50+ - I would like to convert each of these questions into a separate row.

My ideal output would be something like:

| SurveyId | QuestionId | QuestionType | QuestionText | QuestionName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abcdef123 | QID16 | DB | question text 16 | question name 16 |
| abcdef123 | QID18 | DB | question text 18 | question name 18 |
| abcdef123 | QID21 | DB | question text 21 | question name 21 |

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**As the required keys in your JSON are dynamic**, you cannot access the values inside keys object in the dataflow and Flatten won't work because its an object not an array of objects.

To achieve your requirement, you can try below workaround which involves combination of Dataflow and copy activity and some manual work. **Please note that if the number of required columns in the output are more or the API response is more than 5000 rows, then this approach might not be a good option**.

First, extract the required `QID` keys in the dataflow using `Select` transformation Rule based mapping.

[image]

Then, take a `derivedColumn` transformation and create a new column `col_names` column and get the `columnNames()` as an array like below.

[image]

Now, take `sink` but use `cache` sink by which we can pass this `col_names` array column to the ADF pipeline.

[image]

Remove the extra columns in the sink mapping.

[image]

If you execute this Dataflow from pipeline, it will pass the required dynamic keys array to the pipeline like below in the activity output.

[image]

Loop through this array and build a new `JSON` with required columns in the pipeline.

To do that we need the original JSON. So, **take a web activity to your API to get that JSON**. Here, I have stored the JSON in blob and used lookup activity to get that JSON.

**Create an array type variable** in the variable section of the pipeline and don't give any default value there.

Give the **col_names** array from the above activity output to the for-loop. Use below expression for that. Check the **Sequential** checkbox in the ForEach activity.

```
@activity('Data flow1').output.runStatus.output.sink1.value[0].col_names
```

Inside loop, take an **Append variable activity** to the created array variable and give the below expression.

```
@json(concat('{"SurveyId":"',activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].result.id,'","QuestionId":"',item(),'","QuestionType":"',activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].result.questions[item()].questionType.type,'","QuestionText":"',activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].result.questions[item()].questionText,'","QuestionName":"',activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].result.questions[item()].questionName,'"}'))
```

[image]

**You need to change the expression of lookup as per the web activity JSON**.

Here, what this expression will do is, it will build an array of objects of required values in each iteration.

It will build the JSON like below after for-loop.

[image]

Now, take a copy activity and in the source, take an SQL dataset but use the query option for the data. Give the below query in it.

```
Declare @myjson VARCHAR(MAX) =N'@{variables('json_arr')}';
SELECT t.SurveyId,t.QuestionId,t.QuestionType,t.QuestionText,QuestionName
FROM OPENJSON(@myjson, '$')
WITH  (
        SurveyId nvarchar(200),
        QuestionId nvarchar(max),
        QuestionType nvarchar(max),
        QuestionText nvarchar(max),
        QuestionName nvarchar(max)) t;
```

[image]

In the copy activity sink, add your target SQL dataset and Debug the pipeline.

**Here's the expected result:**

[image]